# Adding tree Branches and leafs in TreeView

Tags: javafx

i am working on treeView program in which, user need to add branches and leafs here is my example

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane border;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {   
        border = new BorderPane();    
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,200,200); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    

        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<String>("Root");      
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Branch");
        item1.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Leaf"));
        item1.setExpanded(true); 
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        tree.getChildren().addAll(item1);
        TreeView<String> treeView  = new TreeView<String>(tree);

        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> arg0) {
                return new AddMenuTreeCell();
            }
        });

        VBox vbox =new VBox(2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        VBox.setVgrow(treeView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(treeView);      
        border.setLeft(vbox);
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        private TextField textField;
        public AddMenuTreeCell() {

            MenuItem addItem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Branch");
            MenuItem addItem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Leaf");
            menu.getItems().addAll(addItem1,addItem2);
            addItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TreeItem<String> newBranch = 
                            new TreeItem<String>("Brunch");
                                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newBranch);
                }
            });
            addItem2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TreeItem<String> newLeaf = 
                            new TreeItem<String>("leaf");
                                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty && getTreeItem().getParent() == null){
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

With this user can add Branch and Leaf.

But the question is, if user add a Branch it should be like "Branch1" next added branch should be "Branch2", "Branch3",...... same for leafs added in any branch have their numbers.

So that later on user can assign different task to different branches and leafs. Please

Thank you