# Adding multiple tree Branches and leafs in javafx

Tags: javafx, treeview

hi i post this question before but didn't get any answer.  [Adding tree Branches and leafs in TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333169/adding-tree-branches-and-leafs-in-treeview)

i need help, Please have a look at code,

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane border;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {   
        border = new BorderPane();    
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,200,200); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    

        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<String>("Root");      
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Branch");
        item1.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Leaf"));
        item1.setExpanded(true); 
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        tree.getChildren().addAll(item1);
        TreeView<String> treeView  = new TreeView<String>(tree);

        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> arg0) {
                return new AddMenuTreeCell();
            }
        });

        VBox vbox =new VBox(2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        VBox.setVgrow(treeView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(treeView);      
        border.setLeft(vbox);
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        private TextField textField;
        public AddMenuTreeCell() {

            MenuItem addItem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Branch");
            MenuItem addItem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Leaf");
            menu.getItems().addAll(addItem1,addItem2);
            addItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TreeItem<String> newBranch = 
                            new TreeItem<String>("Brunch");
                                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newBranch);
                }
            });
            addItem2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TreeItem<String> newLeaf = 
                            new TreeItem<String>("leaf");
                                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty && getTreeItem().getParent() == null){
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

With this user can add multiple Branches and Leafs.

But the problem is, if user add a Branch it should be like "Branch1" next added branch should be "Branch2", "Branch3",...... same for leafs added in any branch have their numbers.

So that later on user can assign different task to different branches and leafs.

Thank you!

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you problem is that you want to add a numbering to your branches and leafs?

Comment: yes, with multiple adding, numbers increase.

Comment: That's simple you have to add two `Integer` variables one for branches and one for leafs,and then you have to increment them in those actions.

Comment: I tried but didn't work due to lack of experience in java

Comment: I have copied your code and tested it works if I put two `static` `int` or `Integer` : `private static Integer leafCount` and `private static Integer branchCount` variables in the Main class then I initialized them in the `start` method , and in the `addItem1.setOnAction`'s `handle` method I just put the `branchCount++` and in `addItem2.setOnAction`'s the `leafCount++`. So this way it works the numbering but you have so much code that you can clear and it becomes simple and readable. I guess you want to add to any branch the possibility to add a new branch or leaf this part isn't work.

Comment: I think this comes from the lack of experience but it's fine, by the time you'll learn how to write a cleaner code I will post the answer with the code that I think you expected.

Comment: with this i cannot add new branch's new leaf!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146064/discussion-between-sunflame-and-mudasir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace AddMenuTreeCell class to below code and try now

```
private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
    private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    private TextField textField;
    int i = 1, j = 1;

    public AddMenuTreeCell() {
        MenuItem addItem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Branch");
        MenuItem addItem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Leaf");
        menu.getItems().addAll(addItem1, addItem2);

        addItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                TreeItem<String> newBranch = new TreeItem<String>("Brunch" + i);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newBranch);
                i++;
            }
        });
        addItem2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                TreeItem<String> newLeaf = new TreeItem<String>("leaf" + j);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
                j++;
            }
        });
        setContextMenu(menu);
    }
}
```